# validation using html5 pattern attribute for pin

Tags: regex, html

I am trying to validate pin number ( 6 digits always). I am using,

```
[0-9]{6}
```

Which does the job but it makes field compulsory.

How to make it optional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^([0-9]{6})?$
```

`^` ist string start, `$` is string end, and the `()?` says: My content exactly once or nothing.

However, if I read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) correctly, and [a quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/mtsX4/1/) in FF4 doesn't deceive me, this might not be necessary, as long as you don't add the `required` attribute, too (in which case it would be an error).

Comment: Thanks, it worked really well. One more related que, {6} matches exactly 6 digits. What if I want to match 6 or more?

Comment: `{6,}` would do that. You can read the basics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions